# Using modal popup on top of modal parent window in classic ASP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vbscript

here is some question for gurus here.

I am working on application build in classic ASP(VBScript).

AS we all aware function showModalDialog already declared by some browsers deprecated and others simple support limited use of it. Our app heavily relay on that function and I need to find way to replace it without major recoding.

I did consider using Ajax for this task and using divs sounds like a good idea but problem is that application opens one modal windows on top of the other until entire process is either completed or aborted.

Is it possible to achieve with Ajax or not? I will have to open different files for each modal window and pass parameters to newly opening modal window.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in Ajax as well as Jquery. Both give options for Modal popups.

Check out the Jquery Modal dialog -> [Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)

Check out the AJAX example code and dialog design -> [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/jQuery-Modal-Dialogs.aspx)

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for links but those are for .NET version. Will it work in VBScript app? And second part of the problem that with this approach next modal must be smaller and inside of parent iframe. That is not going to fly with my app.

Comment: Well, Jquery works off of the Javascript client side framework, which isn't really relative to the .NET version's. And you can include the jquery frameworks externally and program them. When you say "VBScript app", is it still running off of a browser? If so, then yes, once you include the Jquery framework, you can utilize jquery. And you can design the jquery forms at will, that's more of an example than anything. If you click the "View Source" button below, you can see all the options.

Comment: Last question Rich, will jquery-1.3.2.js include all those features or I would have to include newest. Asking because that would be either just changes on few components or a major recoding.Sorry that I cannot vote your answers up, but you did gave me an answer.

Comment: According to the dialog widget API documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/ The dialog widget has been native in the jquery framework since 1.0 so you should be good to go my friend! :)